# Content Builder - Send without Subscriber key

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, subscriber-key

In Exacttarget, I want to send a test email to several of my email addresses, however these do not have a set subscriber key.

Before we used the "Classic content" and you had the option to go to "send preview" and then test send where you could manually enter the email address, without it being connected to a subscriber key. 
[image]

However in the new "Content Builder" I do not manage to find this option, and the only way I find to send an email is to send it to a data extension.

However when setting up a DE it has to be connected to a subscriber key or subscriber ID. 
[image]

Is there anyone that could assist me in how to get around this and just send to an email manually that is not connected to a subscriber key/id?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'Preview and Test' option in content builder which is same as classic content 'Send Preview' option. In preview and test you can manually enter email addresses and perform a test send.

Here is the documentation link:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_perform_subscriber_preview_test_send.htm&type=5

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sonali, perhaps I need to check if there is an updated needed, as we only have the "Preview" option and not the "Preview and test" as your screen show.

Comment: Once you add the email address and scroll down, you will see 'Send Test' option. I have added screenshot above.

Comment: @JonasLarsson - Judging from your answer (which should be a comment and/or edit to your question, not an answer) I would say this sounds like a permission or role issue. I would verify that you have the correct permissions. If the permissions are correct, then contact global support about the issue to get this option turned on.